# Array handling in bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, syntax

I have a bash script that currently loops over a large array hardcoded in the script. I would like to add an option for a user to provide a small subset of that array. Here is the relevant part of the code and where I'm seeing an issue:

```
echo "Output Options"
echo $outOpts

if [[ -z ${outOpts} ]] # if no subset is provided, run on full set
then
testFiles=(
TEST1
TEST2
TEST3
...
TEST25
)
echo "Files to Parse"
echo $testFiles
else
echo "Files to Parse"
testFiles=$outOpts
echo $testFiles
fi

for file in "${testFiles[@]}"
do
echo "in loop"
echo $file
    if [[ -n $(anotherAlg --format ${input} | grep "name" | grep ${file}) ]]
    then
        echo ${scratchDir}
        ...
    fi
done
```

`${input}` is a path to an input file, and `${scratchDir}` is a path to a directory.

At the command I run:

```
$ ./parsingScript.sh -i /directory/to/file/to/parse.ntf -o /directory/to/output/ -s /directory/for/scratch/ > diagnosticfile.txt
```

So this is the full script with no options specified and everything runs as it should and the echo statements result as shown:

```
Output Options

Files to Parse

TEST1

in loop

TEST1

/directory/for/scratch/
```

if I search through the diagnostic file, I fine that further down I have:

```
in loop

TEST2

/directory/for/scratch/

...

in loop

TEST3

/directory/for/scratch/
```

...
etc.

I am not fluent in bash, so I was surprised to see that the echo within the first if statement didn't print the full array, but only the first element. However, it looks like it is looping fine.

When I add a flag for output options:

```
$ ./parsingScript.sh -i /directory/to/file/to/parse.ntf -o /directory/to/output/ -s /directory/for/scratch/ -outOpts "TEST3 TEST12" > diagnosticfile.txt
```

The echo statements return as such:

```
Output Options

TEST3 TEST12

Files to Parse:

TEST3 TEST12

in loop

TEST3 TEST12
```

[scratch directory path does not print]

The "in loop" does not print again, in this case, so the script breaks completely. My input array is not being accessed the way the hardcoded array is being accessed and that is a problem. I suspect that this is a syntax error.

I am much better at Python and the python version of what I wanted to do is:

```
bigArray=[lots,of,stuff,...]
userArray=[lots,stuff]
subArray=[]

for item in userArray:
    if item in bigArray:
        subArray.append(item)

# subArray=[lots,stuff]
```

Comment: `if item in bigArray:` is slow. In Python, you'd use a `set` to do that faster. In bash, you should use an associative array with your data as keys to do it faster. Do you want the literal thing you asked for, or the faster version?

Comment: BTW, this question is a lot longer and harder to follow than it needs to be. I'm *hoping* that the Python at the end represents the whole of what you're intending to do -- but in an ideal world, we would have only a narrow question asking a specific question (which it would be easier to compare against preexisting duplicates, and which it would be easier to understand and answer comprehensively).

Comment: ...as another aside, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds before asking questions here as a matter of course. And see [BashFAQ #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) re: the dangers of `echo $foo` (if you want to know what's in a variable, `declare -p foo` is *far* more reliable, and will -- additional to avoiding other unwanted behaviors like changing `*` to a list of files -- print the entire contents of an array, not just its first element).

Answer (score 0):

Making `bigArray` an associative array (the bash equivalent to a python dict), to allow O(1) key lookup:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[0-3].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0+ required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

declare -A bigArray=( ['lots']=1 ['of']=1 ['stuff']=1 )
declare -a userArray=( 'lots' 'stuff' 'and-junk-to-discard' )
declare -a subArray=( )

for item in "${userArray[@]}"; do
  if [[ ${bigArray[$item]} ]]; then
    subArray+=( "$item" )
  fi
done

declare -p subArray
```

...[properly emits as output](https://ideone.com/dHK4LY):

```
declare -a subArray=([0]="lots" [1]="stuff")
```